# How can I get the number of updated rows in database when using JPA Repository .save() method in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jparepository

I am trying a simple update in the spring boot project. Here I have tried to get the result of a particular entry populated in form using form backing bean and try to save in turn update it with new details.
The code works fine and the data gets updated. I am using JPA Repository .save method.

- Is there a way to return the no. of updated rows in database when I am using this structure..?!

Code:

```
@Controller
public class NewCustomerController {
    @Autowired
    CustomersRepository customerrepository;
    @Autowired
    Customers customers;

    @RequestMapping(value = "NewCustomer", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String tonewcustomer(ModelMap map) {
        map.addAttribute("customers", new Customers());
        return "NewCustomer";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "createnewcustomer", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String toaddnewcustomer(ModelMap map, @Valid Customers customers, BindingResult result) {
        if (result.hasErrors())
        {
            return "NewCustomer";
        }
        customerrepository.save(customers);
        
        return "CompletionPage";
    }
}
```

The Code is working fine.

- Is there a way to return the no. of updated rows in database when I am using this structure..?!

Comment: JPA is just an interface that can be used by a lot of drivers. If you have to need a special function use the driver directly or use any workaround for your goal. Example (just one idea of many): use unique modify_id for every item when you use the update, so you can count by this id.

Comment: Isn't the number equal customers.size() ?

Comment: Thanks @Numichi I have a more clear picture now about JPA and what to use..! :)